# Print command giving syntax error python

Tags: python, syntax-error

this is my code for a simple function as i'm a beginner

```
def repeat(s, exclaim):
    result = s*3
    if exclaim:
        result = result + '!!!'
    return result
def main():
    print repeat('Yay', False)
    print repeat('Woo Hoo', True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when i run this code it shows an error on the line
 `print repeat('Yay', False)`
syntax error: invalid syntax
please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    print(repeat('Yay', False))
```